# Angular with IBM Northstar

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to integrate a Northstar template into an Angular project but the Northstar elements are enabled only when a view is reloaded not when it is accessed by the regular Angular route.

I downloaded and saved the main js file `www.js`, which also adds jQuery, to the assets folder and included it in index.html like this

```
<script src="./assets/scripts/www.js"></script>
```

The styles are loaded in `angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
    "assets/styles/v18.css"
]
```

So before the refresh a select element looks like this:

[image]

And after the refresh it looks like it should look:

[image]

How can I get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start the element manually:

```
IBMCore.common.widget.selectlist.init("yourSelectlistId", optionalSettingsObject);
```

Docs:
http://northstarexamples.mybluemix.net/v18/docs/classes/IBMCore.common.widget.selectlist.html

Example in Angular2:
`IBMCore.common.widget.selectlist.init($('#id')[0])`

Comment: I think you're right. Not sure why you got downvoted.

Comment: if you are using Angular2:

`IBMCore.common.widget.selectlist.init($('#id')[0])`